# how to handle large size of update query in mysql with laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, file

is There a way that I can update 100k records in a query and mysql database will work smoothly?

Suppose there is a table users containg hundred thousand of records and I have to update approx fifty thousand of records and for update I have IDs of those records means to around fifty thousand of records somewhere stored in csv file,

1 - Will query be ok as size of query would be too large ? or if there is any way to put in smaller chuncks let me know ?

2- Considering laravel framework, if there any option to read a part of file not the whole file, to avoid memory leakage, As I donot want to read all file at the same time, please suggest.

Any suggestion are welcome !

Comment: One alternative would be to load the CSV into a temporary table ( using https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html ) and then using a SQL statement to do the update using SQL.

Answer (score 4):

If you're thinking of building a query like `UPDATE users SET column = 'value' WHERE id = 1 OR id = 2 OR id = 3 ... OR id = 50000` or `WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, ..., 50000)` then that will probably be too big. If you can make some logic to summarize that, it would shorten the query and speed things up on MySQL's end significantly. Maybe you could make it `WHERE id >= 1 AND id <= 50000`.

If that's not an option, you could do it in bursts. You're probably going to loop through the rows of the CSV file, build the query as a big `WHERE id = 1 OR id = 2...` query and every 100 rows or so (or 50 if that's still too big), run the query and start a new one for the next 50 IDs.

Or you could just run 50.000 single `UPDATE` queries on your database. Honestly, if the table makes proper use of indexes, running 50.000 queries should only take a few seconds on most modern webservers. Even the busiest servers should be able to handle that in under a minute.

As for reading a file in chunks, you can use PHP's basic file access functions for that:

```
$file = fopen('/path/to/file.csv', 'r');

// read one line at a time from the file (fgets reads up to the
// next newline character if you don't provide a number of bytes)
while (!feof($file)) {
    $line = fgets($file);

    // or, since it's a CSV file:
    $row = fgetcsv($file);
    // $row is not an array with all the CSV columns

    // do stuff with the line/row
}

// set the file pointer to 60 kb into the file
fseek($file, 60*1024);

// close the file
fclose($file);
```

This will not read the full file into memory. Not sure if Laravel has its own way of dealing with files, but this is how to do that in basic PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on data you have to update, i would suggest few ways:

- If all users would be updated by same value - as @rickdenhaan said,
  you can build multiple batches every X rows from csv.
- If every individual user have to be updated with unique values - you have to run  single queries.
- If any updated columns have indices - you should disable autocommit and do transaction manually to avoid reindex after each single update.

To avoid memory leakage, my opinion is the same as @rickdenhaan's. You should read csv line by line using the `fgetcsv`

To avoid possible timeouts, for example you can put script processing into laravel queues