# Updating records in a loop with Laravel giving me a 500 server error

Tags: laravel, loops, records

Obviously I'm running out of memory and I realise this is the wrong way to update thousands of records, but what is the right way?

I have an assosiative array which I'm looping through to update record values:

`$array = ['red' => '1', 'blue' => '1', 'green' => '3']`

(obviously this array is a lot larger, around 1000 records.)

Loop through and update like this:

```
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    Colour::where('name', '=', $key)->update(['cost' => $value]);
  }
```

what's the right way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to handle large size of update query in mysql with laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43878260/how-to-handle-large-size-of-update-query-in-mysql-with-laravel)

Comment: 1000 records in the format you've shared is still not that big. Are you sure you're not leaking memory anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of querying the model, and update it - try to update it without fetching:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    DB::table('colors')
        ->where('name', $key)
        ->update(['cost' => $value]);
}
```

For more info, see [Laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#updates)